# Using Fusion Tables API v1.0 with Google Visualization Query Object: Clarification Please

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

With the impending deprecation of the Fusion Tables SQL API in January, I want to ensure my application continues to operate as expected.

I use the Google Visualization api to query the Fusion tables like this:

```js
...
var queryText = encodeURIComponent(querySelect + " FROM " + FT_MarkerTableID + queryWhere);               
var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText); 

query.send(getData);
...
```

The Visualization API documentation still has references to the old Fusion Tables SQL API and not the Fusion Tables API v1.0.

My question is can I simply use the new URL endpoint https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/ and expect the same functionality. It seems this new endpoint does not have "gvizdata" at its root path... Will http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata continue to be available after the Jan 14, 2013 shutdown? Is it just the "api/query" that won't be available.

I would appreciate some guidance on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata endpoint is separate from the SQL API and won't be shut down with the SQL API.

If you are using the gvizdata API for a visualization, then it you can leave your application as is.  If you are using it merely for accessing data, however, we highly encourage you to migrate to the v1.0 API.